# Given two strings ABC and CBA, find A, B and C

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Given two strings ABC and CBA, find A, B and C.

Input:
abcacab, cabcaab

Output:
ab, ca, cab

The time complexity of brute force is O(n^3). Are there any better algorithms to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Please tell where you saw this problem.

Comment: Actually, I want to write code about Example 1.1 in [Genus n forms over Hyperbolic groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1513v1). This problem is the equivalent form.

Comment: Given s1 and s2, for i in range(n+1), check if s2.endswith(s1[:i]) and s1[i:] is a cyclic rotation of s2[:(n-i)].  Checking whether X is a rotation of Y (of the same length) is the same as checking whether X is substring of Y+Y, which can be done in linear time. So we have an algorithm in $O(n^2)$ time.

Comment: Wow, this is a better algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if the time complexity can be further reduced.

Comment: The solution can fail to be unique. What in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by trying to find possible values of A.

A could be an empty string obviously.

Otherwise, you know the last character of A. Let's say that character is the first, fourth and nineteenth character of ABC. Then A could be one character. Or it could be the first four characters of ABC (if it matches the last four characters of CBA. Or it could be that last nineteen characters of ABC (if it matches the last 19 characters of CBA), and so on.

In your example, the last character of CBA was b, which is the second character of ABC, so (apart from A = empty), the only possibility for A was A = ab, leaving BC = cacab, CB = cabca. A = nine characters is not possible because the first and last nine characters of ABC and CBA are different.

For each possible value of A you now have BC and CB. You do the same examination. Except if the last character of B is in position k within BC, then the character k+1 of BC is the first character of CB, so this must also match.

You will be better off if you count which characters occur most often, and check the rarest characters. For example, if you have a million characters, and the character X occurs only once, at position 10 of ABC and 19 characters from the end in CBA then you conclude that A could be 28 characters, or is at most nine characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't seem to be a general solution. The time complexity can't be reduced in the worst case.

Comment: That seems indeed difficult. Well, with k different characters and only looking at the rarest one you should be able to reduce the complexity by k^3. Better if you find the rarest short strings.